# minimizing the Higgs potential equivalent to finding the minimum?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

When my advisor tells me to "minimize the Higgs potential", is she asking me to find the minimum (take the derivative of the potential and set it equal to zero)?

Comment: Your minimum energy principle (*"For a closed system with fixed entropy, the total energy is minimized at equilibrium"*) seems flawed. You might want to have a look at: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47253/ .

Comment: I do not think I am competent enough to answer the question, so I am deleting my answer.

Comment: @user1218748:  Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.  I think maybe I need to provide more information, like you said...

Comment: NP; yes, that would certainly help.

Comment: The whole point of having higgs boson was to have a non zero normalised potential, r8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although rather late in answering (I just came across your question): 
Tomas Brauner, http://arxiv.org/abs/arXiv:1001.5212, section 4.2, gives a general discussion about these matters.